# Why don't emails move in Outlook 2003?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2003, email-filter

When I add a new rule in Outlook 2003 mail, it asks if I want to run the rule in the present folder at that time. I say "Yes", I see it run the rule, but when it is finished, non of the emails have been moved to the new folder. How can I fix this?

XP3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That usually means that emails does not match to created rule.

Comment: Well, I select the message that represents the ones that I receive, for example, the "from" field and run that. So, I am expecting that that will match. ????

Comment: Well, I went back and checked and found out that you were right! Thank you. +1 and accept. Colour me embarrassed. :-)